# Magento: Show different action links in on column in the backend data grid

Tags: php, magento, custom-action, backend

Im currently working on a custom product list in the Magento backend.

Heres the code i am currently using to add a row:

```
$this->addColumn('action_widget',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '110px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'    => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Create Widget'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/create_widget',
                    'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'id'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

that works already as preferred.

But now i want to display another action link when the widget is already created (update widget) instead of the create link. To know that the widget isalready created i joined to the collection an attribute that is null when it doesn't exists or is a string when it does exist.

I've already tried to use a custom grid template file, put a {actionAssign} 'variable' into the url and assign that in the template, but the magento url validation denied that.

Is there any way to do this without a huge workaround?

If not, is it possible to create disabled links depending on the attribute in my product collection?

Thanks to everyone! MRu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need create custom grid column renderer for this:

1. Create class and override _transformActionData() or render() method, it depends on what exactly you need:

   ```
   class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Myrendered extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action 
   {
     ... 
   }
   ```
2. Tell magento to use custom renderer for this column:

   ```
   // ...
   'filter'    => false,
   'renderer'  => 'mycompany_mymodule/adminhtml_template_grid_renderer_myrenderer',
   'sortable'  => false,
   'index'     => 'stores',
   // ...
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Following code is working for me.

```php
 $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('orderreminder')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getOrderId',
                'actions'   => array(
                  array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('orderreminder')->__('View Order'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> 'adminhtml/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'     => 'order_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'renderer'  => 'Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Myrendered',
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
            ));
```

```php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Myrendered extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
       $value = $row->getData('increment_id');
        if($value = $row->getData('increment_id'))
            return '<a href="'.$this->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view',array('order_id'=>$row->getData('order_id'))).'">View Order</a>';
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who tried Zyava's answer and it didn't work, you might need to do this instead:

```
'filter'    => false,
'renderer'  => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('mycompany_mymodule/adminhtml_template_grid_renderer_myrenderer'),
'sortable'  => false,
'index'     => 'stores',
```

I don't know where the bug is, as this shouldn't be necessary, but... it was for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler method:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('action1',
        array(
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'frame_callback' => array($this, 'decorateRow'),
            'actions' => array( ... )
            'index' => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
        ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function decorateRow($sVal, Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $oRow){
    return $oRow->getData('something') ? '' : $sVal;
}
```

Comment: easier than using a renderer!